# Click e segurar no ListView

Tags: android, listview, click

Como programo para ao click e manter pressionado chame um método diferente de somente um click normal no ListView?

Gostaria de dicas, tutorias algo que possa me ajudar.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), inalcancaveis_tela.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

chamo esse metodo no onCreateView

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

OBS: to utilizando extends Fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça sua classe implementar o evento para long clique `implements OnItemLongClickListener`
E utilize o método `onItemLongClick` como abaixo:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), inalcancaveis_tela.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

no `onCreate` de sua classe agora você deve chamar esse método para registrar seu evento:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

Abs

Comment: Obrigado, se eu precisar utilizar o onItemClick teria como? e como eu poderia implementá-lo?

Comment: Oi Guilherme para utilizar o onItemClick em conjunto com o onItemLongClick basta implementar o evento OnItemClickListener e realizar a chamada para registrar: list.setOnItemClickListener(this); serão dois métodos separados, cada um tratando um evento diferente.